# How to get real three digits of microseconds in Python?

Tags: python, date-format

I'm trying to increase the time.

I want to get an hour format like this: `13:30:45,123` (in Java: `"HH:mm:ss,SSS"`), but Python displays `13:30:45,123456` (`"%H:%M:%S,%f"`)(microseconds of 6 digits).

I read on the web and found possible solutions like:

```
from datetime import datetime
hour = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]
print(hour)
```

The output is: `04:33:16,123`

But it's a bad solution, because if the hour is for example: `01:49:56,020706`, the output is: `01:49:56,020`, that the right should be: `01:49:56,021` (rounded).

---

The real purpose is that if I increase the milliseconds, even reaching rounds the seconds.
Example: (*I want to increase 500 microseconds*)

If the Input: `00:01:48,557`, the Output should be: `00:01:49,057`

The code of the program in Java (working good) is:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss,SSS");            
System.out.print("Input the time: ");
t1 = in.next();

Date d = df.parse(t1);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();            
cal.setTime(d);
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 500);//here increase the milliseconds (microseconds)

t2 = df.format(cal.getTime());            
System.out.print("The Output (+500): "+t2);
```

I don't know if exists in Python something like `SimpleDateFormat` (in Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to *addition*, you can add 500ms to your `datetime` object, using a `timedelta` object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
t1 = datetime.utcnow()
t2 = t1 + timedelta(milliseconds=500)
```

So as long as you're working with `datetime` objects instead of strings, you can easily do all the time-operations you'd like.

So we're left with the question of how to *format* the time when you want to display it.

As you pointed out, the `[:-3]`-trick seems to be the common solution, and seems to me it should work fine. If you really care about rounding correctly to the closest round millisecond, you can use the following "rounding trick":

You must have seen this trick in the past, for floats:

```
def round(x):
    return int(x + 0.5)
```

The same idea (i.e. adding 0.5) can also be applied to `datetime`s:

```
def format_dt(t):
    tr = t + timedelta(milliseconds=0.5)
    return tr.strftime('%H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]
```

Comment: Thanks @shx2, you gave a good answer. I invite you to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468319/how-to-extract-and-increment-the-hour-from-text-str-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You can round of digits using `decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal
ts = datetime.utcnow()
sec = Decimal(ts.strftime('%S.%f'))
print ts.strftime('%H:%M:')+str(round(sec, 3))
```